# cannot resolve symbol jsonobject in intellij

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, jackson

[Cannot resolve image:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JkNxI.png)

I am getting the error cannot resolve symbol jsonobject in intellij, shown in the attached image:Cannot resolve image, when I press Alt + Enter it does not give me the option to import class.

```
import org.json.JSONObject;
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Please add this in your pom.xml file

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20190722</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you developing Java project through maven. If so approach shared by Alexandros Kourtis should work. If you are not using Maven, download the org.json library and reference it in the project.

Comment: I am developing through maven, and the approach shared by Alexandros Kourtis works best.

Answer (score 0):

For Gradle developers add this to to your build.gradle dependencies:

```
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json
implementation 'org.json:json:20220924'
```